# Como hacer que mi session dure un año en php7

Tags: php7, session, cookies, setcookie

tengo una pagina en donde se puede registrar e inicial sesión, pero es un poco molesto tener que estar identificándose siempre que cierras el navegador y me gustaría hacer como hacen esas grandes paginas que con solo inicial la sesión una solo vez, ya no tienes que volverla a inicial durante un año, a menos que oprimas el botón de cerrar sesión y tu sesión se destruya. Estuve averiguando un poco en Internet, pero solo logre que mi `cookies` dure un año utilizando la `setcookies`.

Este es mi código para inicial sesión dentro de la pagina y aquí pueden ver como le doy un año de vida a la `cookies`:

```
<?php session_start();

require_once('./conexion/conexion.php');

$errors = '';

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $password = hash('sha512', $password);

    // sentencia para saber si lo que introduce el usuario es correcto
    $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password LIMIT 1");

    $sentencia->execute(array(
        ':email' => $email,
        ':password' => $password
    ));

    $resultado = $sentencia->fetch();

    if($resultado == true){
        setcookie('email', $email, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, '/');
        setcookie('password', $password, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, '/');

        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header('Location: ./');
    } else {
        $errors .= "* Has escrito mal el correo electrónico o la contraseña";
    }
}
```

---

Olvide mencionar algo y es que no se porque razón en el correo electrónico me sale %40 en vez de el @ en el correo electrónico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También quiero aclarar que lo que en realidad yo quiero es que cuando yo cierre el navegador y vuelva a abrirlo mi sesión este iniciada y no tenga que logiarme nuevamente.
Como lo hacen grandes plataformas, no se si me di a entender bien.

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: el problema esta en que cierro el navegador y tengo nuevamente que logiarme para entrar al sistema y no se queda iniciada o recordada la sesión

Comment: ¿Podrías decir el sistema operativo y versión que usas en el servidor? Dependiendo de ello la respuesta cambia.

Comment: las grandes plataformas usan tokens que expiran y se renuevan cada cierto tiempo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema radica en la configuración de las cookies de sesión. Por defecto PHP tiene configurado el parámetro [`session.cookie_lifetime`](https://php.net/es/session.configuration#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) a `0`:

> `session.cookie_lifetime` especifica el tiempo de vida en segundos de la cookie que es enviada al navegador. El valor `0` significa "hasta que el navegador se cierre". Por defecto es `0`.

De modo que deberás cambiar su valor en el archivo `php.ini` a un año (`31536000` segundos) para evitar que la cookie de sesión de PHP se borre al cerrar el navegador.

Además, si usas un servidor Apache con la opción adecuada activa, podrás incluir lo siguiente en el archivo `.htaccess` para cambiar ese parámetro sólo para las páginas de ese directorio y subdirectorios:

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 31536000
```

Podrías hacer uso, también, de [`session_get_cookie_params()`](https://php.net/es/function.session-get-cookie-params) para obtener los mismos resultados.

---

Pero todo esto tiene un **pero** muy importante a tener en cuenta:

Por norma general existe un proceso programado en el sistema operativo que borra todos los archivos de sesión (aquellos archivos que contienen la relación entre la cookie de sesión y los datos de sesión) cuando tienen una antigüedad superior a [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](https://php.net/es/session.configuration.ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) o bien tras iniciar el sistema de sesiones (depende de otro parámetro de configuración), así que para evitar que el recolector de basura elimine los archivos relacionados deberás configurar también ese parámetro con el mismo valor.

---

**Implicaciones de seguridad:** ¿Realmente necesitas almacenar durante un año los datos de sesión de un usuario?

Piensa que si la cookie de sesión es interceptada o robada, durante un año podrán hacerse pasar por tu usuario.

Comment: la funciona *session_get_cookie_params('lifetime');* me ha servido para lo que quiero, aun que no se si baya a durar un año con la sesion iniciada, pero en realidad eso es lo que busco que aun que cierre el navegador y vuelva a abril el navegador mi sesión este iniciada con mi usuario y por lo visito lo he logrado con esa función *session_get_cookie_params('lifetime');* que me recomendó **OscarGarcia**. Note que al escribir en mi código la función *session_get_cookie_params('lifetime');* ahora cierro el negador y al abrirlo la sesión sigue iniciada, aunque no se por cuanto tiempo estará así, c